# My pc is showing black screen after booting. I failed the update process

Tags: fedora, boot, upgrade

Today i tried to update fedora and when it was installing the update my pc got turned off because the charger had some problem. When i tried it to boot its not booting. First it shows fedora then a blank black screen with a blinking dot

My laptop is lenovo thinkpad t430
Please help i want my data . Help

Comment: After changing that it shows black screen again, how can i roll back to previous version. I changed quiet rhgb and crt +x and then many words came and the black screen cameback

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it. I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and logged in through the terminal. Then I ran `sudo dnf update` and restarted. Everything got fixed.